# window.location after insertion in sqlite not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am working with phonegap+sqlite.

I am trying to insert something.

Here is the code-

```
function insertDB() {
        var sqlI = "INSERT INTO post_data(post_text,pdate) VALUES("Hello, world","23-05-2012");
        mydb.transaction(
                             function(transaction) {
                             transaction.executeSql(sqlI, [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler); 
                             });
        console.log("inserted");
        window.location="dashboard.html";
}
```

I am able to insert data when I remove the line `window.location="dashboard.html"` or when i set a delay of 1000ms, and then execute `window.location="dashboard.html"`. But the above code does not work. Why?

Comment: Is it the insert or the redirection which doesn't work?

Comment: Redirection works. Insertion does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `transaction` function is asynchronous. 
Try and put the redirection just above :

```
mydb.transaction(
    function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(
            sqlI, 
            [],  
            function(transaction, results){
                // passing transaction and results in case you have to display some returned statements
                window.location="dashboard.html";
            },
            nullDataHandler
        ); 
});
```

As you can see, the redirection would be handled in the resultHandler.

Comment: Wow, this worked. I did not know that transaction function was asynchronous. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it's. Just in cas I wasn't clear about the `function(transaction, results)` statement : you can simply use `function()` instead if you won't handle the result and you can then have (theorically) better performances.